# Spotfire: Changing Pivot Data by Filtering Original Data

Tags: spotfire

I have managed to enter a data table into Spotfire (version 6.0) and create a pivot from the data table. However I am unable to make it such that when I filter the original data, the pivot reacts to the filter and gets recalculated accordingly.

I am trying to find a way to do this without any coding per se, just trying to see if there is a particular setting that enables this to happen.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Example**

If I originally have the following table

`age   loc   own1   own2   own3
 24     W      1      0      1 
 38     N      1      1      0 
 16     N      0      0      0 
 58     S      1      0      0 
 33     W      0      1      1 
 45     N      1      1      1 
 23     S      1      0      0 
 62     N      0      1      0`

and then I create a pivot on this table to calculate the sum of each own column by location, so by choosing row identifiers as loc, no column titles and values as sum(own*) I get:

`loc     own3   own2   own1
 string  real   real   real
 N       1.00   3.00   2.00
 S       0.00   0.00   2.00
 W       2.00   1.00   1.00`

So from this, how can I make the values of the pivot table automatically adjust when I change the filter of the original table. So for example if I change the age filter to above 30 then it will change to:

`loc     own3   own2   own1
 string  real   real   real
 N       1.00   3.00   2.00
 S       0.00   0.00   1.00
 W       1.00   1.00   0.00`

Comment: If you could post some sample data and some more info about the steps you took I'd be happy to try and help.

Comment: Have edited OP, if I have missed anything else out let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your data set and pasted it into Spotfire and achieved what you described using a Cross Table visualization. The image below should help you see what to do. Notice that I filtered the age column for 31-62 and the results match the figures in the third data sample you provided.

[image: Cross Table with Filtering]